# Pandas: Grouping DataFrame by hundreds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame, grouped by date. Prompt me how to use `df.groupby()`, or some other approach in Pandas to group a DataFrame by hundreds? For example, I want to get in order the first hundred of values, then the next one hundred and so on.

Comment: just iterate over a step slice of the df: `for chunk in df.iloc[::100]: #domsoemthing with chunk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

This should work:

```
df.groupby({x: x // 100 for x in range(len(df))})
```

### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(501)})
grouped = df.groupby({x: x // 100 for x in range(len(df))})
```

Test it.

Summing:

```
>>> grouped.sum()

       a
0   4950
1  14950
2  24950
3  34950
4  44950
5    500
```

Double check:

```
>>> df.a[:100].sum()
4950

>>> df.a[100:200].sum()
14950

>>> df.a[300:400].sum()
34950

>>> df.a[400:500].sum()
44950

>>> df.a[500:].sum()
500
```

Counting:

```
>>> grouped.count()

     a
0  100
1  100
2  100
3  100
4  100
5    1
```